# The Windows equivalent of /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ for suspend notification

Tags: windows, visual-studio, events, signals, suspend

My application, in C, compiled with VisualC 2019, needs to know when the OS goes to sleep.

Under Linux, I use `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` for this, where you can [simply place a script](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html) that gets run on going to sleep/suspend.

In Windows, what would be the way to achieve this in the C programming language?

I need my app to do some housekeeping just before the OS goes to sleep, so I need a trigger for that.

I want to avoid C# and dot Net, so would like to achieve this with plain function calls into the Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for `WM_POWERBROADCAST` or call [`PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-powerregistersuspendresumenotification).